# Java FX - Data FX - Loading a CSV file into a TableView

Tags: csv, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to load the content of a CSV file into a TableView using DataFX. I've created a new JavaFX project, that does nothing but loading this file in the background. In the controller, I have the following code

```
File file = new File("test.csv");
            if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
                DataSourceReader dsr1 = new FileSource(file);  
                String[] cols ={"FNAME","LNAME","ADDRESS"};
                MyCSVDataSource ds1 = new MyCSVDataSource(dsr1, cols);
                TableView tableView = new TableView();
                tableView.setItems(ds1.getData());

                System.out.println("CSV : " + ds1.getData().size());
```

ds1.getData().size() always returns zero. I've taken care of spaces, column names, etc. The CSV is extremely simple and I've wrote it with NotePad++:

```
FNAME,LNAME,ADDRESS
Frank,Noris,42 iOpus Drive
Ann,Coleman,PO Box 12345
Thomas,Test,1 Bills Drive
```

Since I could not figure what was the problem, I've downloaded the source code of CSVDataSource.java and DataSource.java and used those instead, so I can set some println and use the debugger to analyse. So in the background, CSVDataSource creates an inner class and a service, which uses to load the contents of the file. I've added a println within the task execution function:

```
@Override
protected Task createTask() {
    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myReader.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                String line;
                int row = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    }
```

Executing all together the output is the following:

```
CSV : 0
FNAME,LNAME,ADDRESS
Frank,Noris,42 iOpus Drive
Ann,Coleman,PO Box 12345
Thomas,Test,1 Bills Drive
```

With this I understand that the service is executed after I call to ds1.getData().size() although start is called in the CSVDataSource constuctor:

```
public MyCSVDataSource(DataSourceReader reader, String... cols) {
    for (String col : cols) {
        selectedColumnNames.add(col);
    }
    DataRetriever retriever = new DataRetriever(reader);
    retriever.start();       

}
```

So it is zero at the moment ds1.getData().size() is called. Can you please confirm if this assupmtion is correct and how to properly load the CSV. FYI, I moved the code to the application file, and the problem persists.

Thank you in advance.